# Difference between VisualVM JVM Arguments and GlassFish/Payara JVM Arguments it's normal?

Tags: jvm, visualvm, payara

I'm trying to starting use VisualVM for tracking some memory leaks I believe i had on my projects, I'm totally new to this tool so please excuse me if I'm asking some obvious thing.

The setup it's all fine, but in the JVM arguments of the Visual VM I saw this:
[image]

They conflict with my Payara JVM Arguments. `-Xms` in Payara is 2048 and the `-Xmx` too.

I need to manually put these configurations on my VisualVM? How I can track the JVM Memory Usage if these arguments differ, like, in a scenario where some application uses 1gb of memory and my VisualVM uses just 768m?

Thanks.

Comment: VIsualVM is itself a java program running in a JVM the args you are displaying here are the args for the VIsualVM JVM, and presumably not the JVM you want profile.

Comment: Ok, I know I have only one JRE in my machine, if I let these args for the VisualVM can I track the memory usage of the JVM even with less memory on the VisualVM? If I get it right, these arguments are just to VisualVM to run, nothing more, so they doesn't matter.

Comment: Ordinary memory usage tracking means processing a few numbers, so VisualVM’s heap memory doesn’t matter. Only when you want to analyze heap dumps, it may become relevant.

Comment: Now I get it. Thank both for the answers.